# I need to add a list of 1000 integers between 1 and 100 in an array along with their occurrences and then display them

Tags: java

The instructions for this assignment are as follows:

> Text file numbers.txt contains 1000 integers vary from 1 to 100. You need to
>
> 1. Use an ArrayList (Required) to store all integers. If one number appears multiple times in text file, only save the first occurrence in the ArrayList.
> 2. The output should be saved in one txt file called results.txt
> 3. The output information should be in the following format in the text file.
>
> Numbers 1 to 100 should be in the first column in the order of appearance. Second
> column presents the occurrence times of the corresponding number.

Here is what I tried before realizing that the numbers have to be in the order they originally appear in numbers.txt

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class test
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {   
  
      Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));             
      PrintWriter fileOutput = new PrintWriter(new File("results.txt"));
  
      int cols;
      int rows;
       
      int[][] b = new int [101][2];
      int i = 0;

      int temp;     
      int[] a = new int [1000];
  
      while (fileInput.hasNext())
      {
         a[i] = fileInput.nextInt();
         i++;
      }
                   
      for (int f = a.length - 1; f > 0; f--)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j< f; j++)
         {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) 
            {
               temp = a[j];
               a[j] = a[j + 1];
               a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
         }
      }
  
      int s = 1;
      int t = 0;
  
      for(int w = 0;w < a.length; w++)
      {
         if (s==a[w])
     {
        t++;
        b[s][0]=s;
     }else if(s<=a[w])
         {
            s=a[w];
        
            b[s][1]=t;
            t=0;
        
            t++;
         }
      }
  
      for (int[] arr : b) 
      {
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

I really have no idea how to go about this. I originally used a Bubble sort and then was able to work my way through it, but I noticed right at the end that the numbers have to be in the order of appearance. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a posted homework assignment without any accompanying code.

Comment: Bubble sort?  I see no reason for any sort.  You just need an input array with 1000 values between 1 and 100 and another array to count the number of times each one appears.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to add the read number to the array list with count being 1 at first.
If the read number is already in the list increase the count.
Later iterate over the ArrayList and print the number and the count into the result file.

No need for sorting

Answer (score 0):

Attack the problem in stages, baby steps often get you going much faster than building the whole solution in your head, banging it all out, and then wondering which part has the bug. (Hint there's usually more than one bug)  This gets all numbers from input into array list:

```
ArrayList<int> nbrs = new ArrayList<int>();    
while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
  nbrs.add(fileInput.nextInt());
}
```

But it doesn't omit repeats, is there an ArrayList method that can help you? Checking Javadoc tells you yes. So refactor:

```
ArrayList<int> nbrs = new ArrayList<int>();    
while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
  int i = fileInput.nextInt();
  if (!nbrs.contains(i)) {
    nbrs.add(i);
  }
}
```

Now you have all numbers from the input, in order, and no duplicates.  But you still need to count the duplicates, and output everything.  Refactor again, and again, and again...  Have fun.  There are often many ways to tackle a goat.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you not to use arraylist here becasue for each number you need to call contains() which takes O(n) time. You should better use HashMap or LinkedHashMap(If u need to maintain insertion order) which takes less time.Store each number as key and occurrence as value.

Comment: The assignment REQUIRES using ArrayList